# Como usar MDX en react

Tags: reactjs, markdown, mdx

Estoy intentando usar MDX en react para poder mostrar el contenido de un array (en mdx), uso está librería https://mdxjs.com/getting-started/create-react-app  en el ejemplo obtiene los datos que va a printear desde un documento, como podría printear el contenido que tengo yo en mi array?
En el caso del ejemplo lo importa desde otro archivo, en mi caso lo tengo un un array.

```
import React, {lazy, Component, Suspense} from 'react'
import {importMDX} from 'mdx.macro'
const Content = lazy(() => importMDX('./Content.mdx'))
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
          <Content />
        </Suspense>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default App
```

Este es el ejempo en MDX

```
const mi_array = [
  "# Project Title
  One Paragraph of project description goes here",
  "## Getting Started system.",
  "### Abcdefghi"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

no he usado MDX, no obstante para invocar un elemento de un array es

```
{modulo_donde_almacenas_tu_aray.nombre_de_array.['index'].id_o_elemento}
```

Comment: Se como recorrer un array en js, lo que no se es como renderizarlo con mdx :/